# AddGestureRecognizer not working for UILabel in tableViewCell

Tags: swift

I am trying to add tap event in `UILabel` inside `tableView` cell as below.

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(downloadFile(_:)))
let msgLabel = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel
msgLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
msgLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

This is my `downloadFile` function.

```
@objc func downloadFile(_ sender:Any){
    print("tapped")
}
```

Can anyone solve this problem for me.

Comment: Where is this code written? Can you add the code for the full tableViewCell?

Comment: It was written in tableView cellForRowAt everything is working fine. I can connect these UILabel inside tableViewCell with my model from API. The problem here is I can't get tap event for that msgLabel.

Comment: Are you using custom cells ?

Comment: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OwnMsg", for: indexPath)
Yes, I am using cell like that. @vivekDas

Comment: where is your downloadFile method defined ?

Comment: This is not a good practice to add gesture in cellForRow method, in the custom cell you must add the gesture and handle the action. And using delegate or completion handler block you should pass the touch action to your VC.

Comment: Could you please explain me a bit more detail with code or could u please share me link? @vivekDas

Comment: I have added my ans plz check.

Answer (score 0):

```
tap.delegate =self;
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
```

Add the above code to `UITapGestureRecognizer` object. That will make it :

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(downloadFile(_:)))
tap.delegate =self;
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
let msgLabel = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel
msgLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
msgLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Comment: @MinKhantLu I hope table view's user interaction is also enabled ?

Answer (score 0):

I propose an alternative by subclassing UITableViewCell. Then you create your downloadFile method inside your custom TableView Cell.

Don't forget to replace `self` with `cell` in tapGesture target:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: cell, action: #selector(cell.downloadFile(_:)))
```

I will explain more further...

**First Step:** Create custom cell

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @objc func downloadFile() {
        print("download")
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

**Second Step:** Typecast your UITableViewCell in your tableView datasource (cellForRowAt)

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! CustomTableViewCell

 let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: cell, action: #selector(cell.downloadFile(_:)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the gesture recognizer in your UITableViewCell subclass.

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{

var exampleLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

func initViews(){

    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(labelTapped))
    exampleLabel.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    print(exampleLabel.frame)
}

@objc func labelTapped(){
    print("Do something here")
}
}
```

The above code would require you to have a cell of type CustomTableViewCell registered in your UITableView from your storyboard. If you are not using storyboard, please change the code accordingly and maybe add the initView method to didMoveToWindow override.

In your controller class, the protocol overrides should follow something of this sort:

```
extension HomeController: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 30
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SomeIdentifierString", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    return cell
}
}
```

Irrelevant to the actual question, but I would like to add that if you are not using storyboard, add the following line to register the UITableViewCell subclass:

```
let exampleTable = UITableView.init(frame: self.view.frame, style: .plain)
self.view.addSubview(exampleTable)
exampleTable.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SomeIdentifierString")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lazy var

```swift
lazy var label: UILabel = {
   let label = UILabel()
   label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
   label.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(downloadFile)))
   return label
}()
```